# Clipboard doesn't work across applications anymore

Tags: macos, copy-paste

Recently, I have noticed that <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> keyboard shortcuts no longer work like they used to. If I want to copy/paste something from Postman.app into Slack.app, for example, the clipboard will only paste what was copied a long time ago inside of Slack.app. It seems like each application now has it's own clipboard and nothing is being shared?

What happened? How can I fix this? I can copy/paste inside an app just fine, but the second I want to paste something from another app it does not work.

I am using a Mid 2015, 15" retina Macbook Pro running OS X El Capitan 10.11.6.

Comment: Does going back to the first app and copying again _after_ you've tried unsuccessfully to paste into the 2nd app change anything? Also could we get your OSX version and Mac model?

Comment: @Scottmeup Updated - It does not change anything no matter how many times I try to re-copy and re-paste.

Comment: @Steve While knowing the version of macOS does helps in getting relevant answer quickly, the issue has nothing to do with version of macOS you are running. You should not jump to the conclusion that you will need to upgrade.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `Postman` or `Slack` apps, but I have noticed strange 'copy-and-paste' behavior in the `XQuartz` app. When using `XQuartz`, I must use `control-c` and `control-v` instead of `command-c` or `-v`.

Comment: Did you try rebooting?

Comment: Re rebooting, see [Strange Clipboard behaviour on OS X El Capitan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/215411/strange-clipboard-behaviour-on-os-x-el-capitan).

Comment: I had [the same issue](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332695/mac-not-copying-and-pasting-between-applications/371380) on Mac 10.13.6 which was resolved by upgrading to Mojave