# Mac not copying and pasting between applications

Tags: macos, copy-paste

Today, I found when I copy from one application into my clipboard, the clipboard cannot be pasted into another application.

The next application has its own clipboard.

If I paste into the first application I see what I just copied.

If I paste into the second application I see what I copied perhaps an hour ago.

So, clipboard copy and paste has become application specific.

How do I turn this off?

Thanks.

**EDIT**, I'm on Mac 10.13.6, and I could not copy between Firefox and Chrome. Rebooting cured the problem.

Comment: Does this happen between all applications or only specific ones? Do you have any helper apps like Hazel, TextExpander or similar installed? Which version of macOS are you running?

Comment: Telling us the applications concerned would be very handy... One other possibility is to take an image then import that image...

Comment: Might be the same issue as https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332568/clipboard-doesnt-work-across-applications-anymore, however there's no answer there yet either.

Comment: @Lizzan one of the comments may be relevant ie the difference between the use of control key compared to the command key...

Comment: I'm on Mac 10.13.6, and I could not copy between Firefox and Chrome. Rebooting cured the problem. I don't have any helper apps like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had no helper applications installed.

Since upgrading to Mojave, this issue has not reoccured.